# How do I add items to the Bluemix catalog for my space?

Tags: ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry

I've been able to add a service broker to my space by using:

```
cf create-service-broker "Service" "<user>" "<password>" "http://<domain>/api" --space-scoped
```

I can then use that service at the command line with:

```
cf create-service Service free service
```

But then in the Bluemix UI, it doesn't appear in my catalog. How can I get it to appear in the catalog in the UI for other users of my space to see?

Comment: I did the same and once I provisioned the service (`create service`) the service shows about in the dashboard. Are you using the classic or new console? I can see my services in both.

Comment: Classic console, but I'll check the new one as well. I'm wondering if I haven't used all the fields I need in my json, but I thought it was pretty complete. Could you post what you used?

Comment: The service only showed up once it was provisioned. I didn't even use all fields and my was based off the echo service broker on GH (don't have the URL handy).

Comment: Ah, then maybe it's not supposed to show in the catalogue, just on the dashboard. Did you provision on the command line? Thanks for following up.

Comment: I provisioned on the command line. More details and instructions in my tutorial that I created http://blog.4loeser.net/2016/10/bluemix-how-to-register-your-own.html

Answer (score 0):

Services advertised by a space-scoped private broker show up in the catalog, depending on which "catalog" is meant. Once the broker has been registered the service can be seen in your view of the marketplace (`cf marketplace`).

After a service has been provisioned (your `cf create-service`) the service can be seen in your Bluemix dashboard.

I created a tutorial explaining all the steps for both space-scoped and standard private brokers: https://github.com/data-henrik/Bluemix-ServiceBroker